# parse Json array error "jsonObject cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have the following Json and I want to parse the array (cars) ,

```
[
{
"name": "John",
"city": "Berlin",
"cars": [
"audi",
"bmw"
],
```

when i tried with the following code i got error

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(
            "C:\\General\\Json\\json.txt"));

    for (Object o : a) {
        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

        String name = (String) person.get("name");
        System.out.println(name);

        String city = (String) person.get("city");
        System.out.println(city);

        String job = (String) person.get("job");
        System.out.println(job);

    }
```

here is the error **"jsonObject cannot be resolved"**
how should i overcome it?

```
JSONArray cars = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cars");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 you did not declared jsonObject
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONArray cars = (JSONArray) person.get("cars");  try this instead of                      JSONArray cars = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cars"); this PSR also correct